# How to create a grouped bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, grouped-bar-chart

**The goal here is to create a grouped bar plot, not subplots like the image below**

Is there a simple way to create a grouped bar plot in Python? Right now I get separate bar plots, instead of separate bars on one plot.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['g1', 'c1', 10], ['g1', 'c2', 12], ['g1', 'c3', 13], ['g2', 'c1', 8], ['g2', 'c2', 10], ['g2', 'c3', 12]], columns=['group', 'column', 'val'])

  group column  val
0    g1     c1   10
1    g1     c2   12
2    g1     c3   13
3    g2     c1    8
4    g2     c2   10
5    g2     c3   12
    

df.groupby(['group']).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Pandas will show grouped bars by columns. Entries in each row but different columns will constitute a group in the resulting plot. Hence you need to "reshape" your dataframe to have the "group" as columns.
In this case you can pivot like

```
df.pivot("column", "group", "val")
```

producing

```
group   g1  g2
column        
c1      10   8
c2      12  10
c3      13  12
```

Plotting this will result in a grouped bar chart.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([['g1','c1',10],['g1','c2',12],['g1','c3',13],['g2','c1',8],
                   ['g2','c2',10],['g2','c3',12]],columns=['group','column','val'])

df.pivot("column", "group", "val").plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

- Given a dataframe of long (tidy) data, as shown in the OP, an implementation that does not require transforming the dataframe is to use [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) with the `hue` parameter.
- [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) is a high-level API for [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/)
- Tested with `seaborn 0.11.1` and `matplotlib 3.4.2`

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# the sample dataframe from the OP
df = pd.DataFrame([['g1', 'c1', 10], ['g1', 'c2', 12], ['g1', 'c3', 13], ['g2', 'c1', 8], ['g2', 'c2', 10], ['g2', 'c3', 12]], columns=['group', 'column', 'val'])

# plot with seaborn barplot
sns.barplot(data=df, x='column', y='val', hue='group')
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can simply do this using the code given below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

positive_values = [20, 17.5, 40]
negative_values = [15, 8, 70]
index = ['Precision', 'Recall', 'f1-score',]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Positive Values': positive_values,
                    'Negative Values': negative_values}, index=index)
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0, color={"Positive Values": "green", "Negative Values": "red"})
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

Plotly express is one of the best visualisation packages I've recently used. It allows you to generate visualisations without needing to perform massive data transformations.

```
# initial dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['g1','c1',10],['g1','c2',12],['g1','c3',13],['g2','c1',8],
                   ['g2','c2',10],['g2','c3',12]],columns=['group','column','val'])

df.head()

   group column val
0   g1   c1     10
1   g1   c2     12
2   g1   c3     13
3   g2   c1      8
4   g2   c2     10
5   g2   c3     12
```

No need to transform data, directly use plotly express:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df, x="column", y="val",
             color='group', barmode='group',text="val",
             height=400)
fig.show()
```

[image: grouped bar chart]