# Matplotlib: How make space between 2 string chars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, charts

I want make  2 charts with space
if I write:

```
x_axis_1 = ['A','B','C']
y_axis_1 = [5,10,15]
y_axis_2 = [7,3,4]
plt.figure(figsize = (15,6))
plt.bar(x_axis_1-0.2, y_axis_1)
plt.bar(x_axis_1+0.2, y_axis_2)
plt.show()
```

I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'
```

because `x_axis` is strings

How I can change this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Create Bar Chart Comparing 2 sets of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182452/python-create-bar-chart-comparing-2-sets-of-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# You can use this to create a figure and axes in one line
# If you want to make 4 plots in a square configuration you'd need
# fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2,figsize=(15,6))
# Google how to do multiplots in matplotlib.
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(15,6))

x_axis_1 = ['A','B','C']
y_axis_1 = [5,10,15]
y_axis_2 = [7,3,4]
ax1.bar(x_axis_1, y_axis_1)
ax2.bar(x_axis_1, y_axis_2)
plt.show()
```

PS: Include `import` statements in your code. It's annoying to have to look what modules you are using myself.

PSS: using minus on a python list never works, even if it is filled with numbers. If you want to do that sort of thing you need numpy arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
array = np.array([1,2,3,2,1])
print(array-0.2)
```

EDITED CORRECT VERSION:

So this is it:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))

# you need to define a bar width for alignment later on
bar_width = 0.35

# Those are just labels, not the positions
x_axis_labels = ['A','B','C']
# Those are just positions, not labels
x_axis_1 = np.arange(len(x_axis_labels))
y_axis_1 = np.array([5,10,15])
y_axis_2 = np.array([7,3,4])

ax.bar(x_axis_1, y_axis_1,bar_width)
ax.bar(x_axis_1+bar_width, y_axis_2,bar_width)

# This sets the number of ticks to the number of labels.
# It also aligns the tick positions with the center of the bars. Notice the + bar_width/2
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x_axis_labels))+bar_width/2)
# This sets the three ticks, which are now at the right positions, to your x_axis_labels
ax.set_xticklabels(x_axis_labels)
plt.show()
```

PSSS: Try to formulate your questions more accurately. I had a hard time understanding what you meant. Also this question is a double of this question:[Python Create Bar Chart Comparing 2 sets of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182452/python-create-bar-chart-comparing-2-sets-of-data) .

PSSSS: Karma plz. I want to reach 420 Points.

Comment: I need to create a bar next to a bar on the same chart.
No two charts

Answer (score 2):

Your `x_axis_1` is a list of strings so you get this error. You need to pass numeric values for the positioning of bars. I have used `-0.1` and `+0.1` to have the bars placed adjacently.

```
plt.bar(np.arange(3)-0.1, y_axis_1, width=0.2, align='center')
plt.bar(np.arange(3)+0.1, y_axis_2, width=0.2, align='center')
plt.xticks(range(3), x_axis_1)
```

[image]