# Separate two groups of bars in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Do you know if it is possible to separate the bars into two groups of different sizes, but maintaining both in the same plot? I have this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [15.3, 25.8, 37.1, 50.0, 15.0, 18.5, 28.9]
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylabel('Reduction Error')
plt.title("")

plt.show()
```

And I would like to have A and B close together, then some space, and then all the other bars. 
I found this issue [Function to create grouped bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796264/function-to-create-grouped-bar-plot), but I would like to keep each name under the bar and not group them as in the example.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would help if you could make a mock up sketch of what you're after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can do in this way:

```
objects = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G')
x = [1,1.8,5,6,7,8,9]
performance = [15.3, 25.8, 37.1, 50.0, 15.0, 18.5, 28.9]

plt.bar(x, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(x, objects)
plt.ylabel('Reduction Error')
plt.title("")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or use `2` instead of `1.8` in `x` to have some space between `A` and `B`

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I meant! Thank you so much!