# How to annotate grouped bar plot with percent by hue/legend group

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot-annotations, grouped-bar-chart

I want to add percentage on the top of bars according to the hue. That means all the red and blue bars are equal to 100% respectively.

I can make the blue bars equal to 100%, but the red bars can't. Which parts should be modified?

### Imports and Sample Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# sample data
np.random.seed(365)
rows = 100000
data = {'Call_ID': np.random.normal(10000, 8000, size=rows).astype(int),
        'with_client_nmbr': np.random.choice([False, True], size=rows, p=[.17, .83]),
        'Type_of_Caller': np.random.choice(['Agency', 'EE', 'ER'], size=rows, p=[.06, .77, .17])}
all_call = pd.DataFrame(data)

   Call_ID  with_client_nmbr Type_of_Caller
0    11343              True             EE
1    14188              True         Agency
2    16539             False             EE
3    23630              True             ER
4    -7175              True             EE
```

### Aggregate and Plot

```py
df_agg= all_call.groupby(['Type_of_Caller','with_client_nmbr'])['Call_ID'].nunique().reset_index()

ax = sns.barplot(x='Type_of_Caller', y='Call_ID', hue='with_client_nmbr',
                 data=df_agg,palette=['orangered', 'skyblue'])

hue_order = all_call['with_client_nmbr'].unique()
df_f = sum(all_call.query("with_client_nmbr==False").groupby('Type_of_Caller')['Call_ID'].nunique())
df_t = sum(all_call.query("with_client_nmbr==True").groupby('Type_of_Caller')['Call_ID'].nunique())

for bars in ax.containers:
    if bars.get_label() == hue_order[0]:
        group_total = df_f
    else:
        group_total = df_t
    for p in ax.patches:
        width = p.get_width()
        height = p.get_height()
        x, y = p.get_xy()
        ax.annotate(f'{(height/group_total):.1%}', (x + width/2, y + height*1.02), ha='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- `print(hue_order)` is `['False', 'True']`

Answer (score 2):

- It's typically not required to use `seaborn` to plot grouped bars, it's just a matter of shaping the dataframe, usually with [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html). See [How to create a grouped bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47796264/7758804) for more examples.

  - Using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with a wide dataframe will be easier, in this case, than using a long dataframe with [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), because the column / bar order and `totals` coincide.
  - This reduces the code from 16 to 8 lines.
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851142/7758804) for adding annotations as a percent of the entire population.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.1`, and `matplotlib 3.4.2`**

### Imports and DataFrame Transformation

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# transform the sample data from the OP with pivot_table
dfp = all_call.pivot_table(index='Type_of_Caller', columns='with_client_nmbr', values='Call_ID', aggfunc='nunique')

# display(dfp)
with_client_nmbr  False   True
Type_of_Caller                
Agency              994   4593
EE                10554  27455
ER                 2748  11296
```

### Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)

- Requires `matplotlib >= 3.4.2`
- Each column is plotted in order, and the `pandas.Series` created by `df.sum()` has the same order as the dataframe columns. Therefore, `zip` `totals` to the plot containers and use the value, `tot`, in `labels` to calculate the percentage by hue group.
- Add custom annotations based on percent by hue group, by using the `labels` parameter.

  - `(v.get_height()/tot)*100` in the list comprehension, calculates percentage.
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for other options using `.bar_label`

```py
# get the total value for the column
totals = dfp.sum()

# plot
p1 = dfp.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8, 4), rot=0, color=['orangered', 'skyblue'], ylabel='Value of Bar', title="The value and percentage (by hue group)")

# add annotations
for tot, p in zip(totals, p1.containers):
    
    labels = [f'{(v.get_height()/tot)*100:0.2f}%' for v in p]
    
    p1.bar_label(p, labels=labels, label_type='edge', fontsize=8, rotation=0, padding=2)

p1.margins(y=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]