# Create a stacked bar plot and annotate with count and percent

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, stacked-bar-chart

I have the following dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib 
print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
# 3.5.3

df=pd.DataFrame({'Type': [ 'Sentence', 'Array', 'String', '-','-', 'Sentence', 'Array', 'String', '-','-', 'Sentence'],
                 'Length': [42,21,11,6,6,42,21,11,6,6,42],
                 'label': [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
                 })
print(df)
#       Type     Length  label
#0   Sentence      42      1
#1      Array      21      1
#2     String      11      0
#3          -       6      0
#4          -       6      0
#5   Sentence      42      1
#6      Array      21      1
#7     String      11      0
#8          -       6      0
#9          -       6      0
#10  Sentence      42      1
```

I want to plot stacked bar chart for the arbitrary column within dataframe (either *numerical* e.g. `Length` column or [*categorical*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029560/plotting-categorical-data-with-pandas-and-matplotlib) e.g. `Type` column) and stack with respect to `label` column using annotations of **both count/percentage**, where small values of rare observations are also displayed. The following script gives me the wrong results:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=True)

#ax = df[["Type","label"]].plot.bar(stacked=True)
#ax = df.groupby('Type').size().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

ax.legend(["0: normanl", "1: Anomaly"])
for p in ax.patches:
    width, height = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    ax.text(x+width/2, 
            y+height/2, 
            '{:.0f} %'.format(height), 
            horizontalalignment='center', 
            verticalalignment='center')
```

I can imagine that somehow I need to calculate the counts of the selected column with respect to `label` column:

```
## counts will be used for the labels
counts = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())

## percents will be used to determine the height of each bar
percents = counts.div(counts.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

I tried to solve the problem by using `df.groupby(['selcted column', 'label']` unsuccessfully. I collected all possible solutions in this Google [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1a_LDUNuVEq3U_ERzIBTVZpvTlbBFsfCs?usp=sharing) nevertheless I couldn't find a straightforward way to adapt into dataframe.

So far I have tried following solution inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70139592/10452700) to solve the problem by using `df.groupby(['selcted column', 'label']` unsuccessfully and I got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' for total = sum(dff.sum())` can't figure out what is the problem? in indexing or `df` transformation.

BTW I collected all possible solutions in this Google [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1a_LDUNuVEq3U_ERzIBTVZpvTlbBFsfCs?usp=sharing) nevertheless I couldn't find a straightforward way to adapt into dataframe via `Mathplotlib`. So I'm looking for an elegant way of using `Seaborn` or `plotly`.

```py
df = df.groupby(["Type","label"]).count()
#dfp_Type   = df.pivot_table(index='Type', columns='label', values= 'Length', aggfunc='mean') 
dfp_Type   = df.pivot_table(index='Type', columns='label', values= df.Type.size(), aggfunc='mean') 
#dfp_Length = df.pivot_table(index='Length', columns='label', values= df.Length.size(), aggfunc='mean') 

ax = dfp_Type.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0) 

# iterate through each bar container
for c in ax.containers: labels = [v.get_height() if v.get_height() > 0 else '' for v in c]

# add the annotations
ax.bar_label(c, fmt='%0.0f%%', label_type='center')

# move the legend
ax.legend(title='Class', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

output:

[image: img]

**Expected output:**

[image: img]

Answer (score 2):

- The values in **Expected output** do not match `df` in the OP, so the sample DataFrame has been updated.
- Plot with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), using `kind='bar'` and `stacked=True`. `pandas` uses and imports `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend, so there's no need to import other plotting libraries.
- Resources:

  - [How to aggregate unique count with pandas pivot_table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68854282/7758804) for details about using `aggfunc=len` in `.pivot_table`.
  - [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for details and examples about `.bar_label`.
  - [How to add multiple annotations to a bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61718127/7758804) & [How to create and annotate a stacked proportional bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523793/7758804) for adding count and percent to a bar plot.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`**

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': [ 'Sentence', 'Array', 'String', '-','-', 'Sentence', 'Array', 'String', '-','-', 'Sentence'],
                   'Length': [42, 21, 11, 6, 6, 42, 21, 11, 6, 6, 42],
                   'label': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]})

# pivot the dataframe and get len
dfp = df.pivot_table(index='Type', columns='label', values='Length', aggfunc=len) 

# get the total for each row
total = dfp.sum(axis=1)

# calculate the percent for each row
per = dfp.div(total, axis=0).mul(100).round(2)

# plot the pivoted dataframe
ax = dfp.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 8), rot=0)

# set the colors for each Class
segment_colors = {'0': 'white', '1': 'black'}

# iterate through the containers
for c in ax.containers:
    
    # get the current segment label (a string); corresponds to column / legend
    label = c.get_label()
    
    # create custom labels with the bar height and the percent from the per column
    # the column labels in per and dfp are int, so convert label to int
    labels = [f'{v.get_height()}\n({row}%)' if v.get_height() > 0 else '' for v, row in zip(c, per[int(label)])]
    
    # add the annotation
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center', fontweight='bold', color=segment_colors[label])
    
# move the legend
_ = ax.legend(title='Class', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.01), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

---

### Comment Updates

- How to always have a spot for `'Array'` if it's not in the data:

  - Add `'Array'` to `dfp` if it's not in `dfp.index`.
  - `df.Type = pd.Categorical(df.Type, ['-', 'Array', 'Sentence', 'String'], ordered=True)` does not ensure the missing categories are plotted.
- How to have all the annotations, even if they're small:

  - Don't stack the bars, and set `logy=True`.
- This uses the full-data, which was provided in a link.

```py
# pivot the dataframe and get len
dfp = df.pivot_table(index='Type', columns='label', values='Length', aggfunc=len) 

# append Array if it's not included
if 'Array' not in dfp.index:
    dfp = pd.concat([dfp, pd.DataFrame({0: [np.nan], 1: [np.nan]}, index=['Array'])])
    
# order the index
dfp = dfp.loc[['-', 'Array', 'Sentence', 'String'], :]

# calculate the percent for each row
per = dfp.div(dfp.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100).round(2)

# plot the pivoted dataframe
ax = dfp.plot(kind='bar', stacked=False, figsize=(10, 8), rot=0, logy=True, width=0.75)

# iterate through the containers
for c in ax.containers:
    
    # get the current segment label (a string); corresponds to column / legend
    label = c.get_label()
    
    # create custom labels with the bar height and the percent from the per column
    # the column labels in per and dfp are int, so convert label to int
    labels = [f'{v.get_height()}\n({row}%)' if v.get_height() > 0 else '' for v, row in zip(c, per[int(label)])]
    
    # add the annotation
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='edge', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
    
# move the legend
ax.legend(title='Class', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.01), loc='upper left')

# pad the spacing between the number and the edge of the figure
_ = ax.margins(y=0.1)
```

[image]

---

### DataFrame Views

- Based on the sample data in the OP

#### `df`

```py
        Type  Length  label
0   Sentence      42      1
1      Array      21      1
2     String      11      0
3          -       6      0
4          -       6      0
5   Sentence      42      1
6      Array      21      1
7     String      11      0
8          -       6      0
9          -       6      1
10  Sentence      42      0
```

#### `dfp`

```py
label       0    1
Type              
-         3.0  1.0
Array     NaN  2.0
Sentence  1.0  2.0
String    2.0  NaN
```

#### `total`

```py
Type
-           4.0
Array       2.0
Sentence    3.0
String      2.0
dtype: float64
```

#### `per`

```py
label          0       1
Type                    
-          75.00   25.00
Array        NaN  100.00
Sentence   33.33   66.67
String    100.00     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I slightly adjusted the data so the graph would look identical to yours(e.g., `Type`:`-`'s `label` has three `0` and one `1`)

```
df
###
        Type  Length  label
0   Sentence      42      1
1      Array      21      1
2     String      11      0
3          -       6      0
4          -       6      0
5   Sentence      42      1
6      Array      21      1
7     String      11      0
8          -       6      0
9          -       6      1
10  Sentence      42      0



df_plot = df.groupby(['Type','label']).size().reset_index()
df_plot.columns = ['Type', 'Class', 'count']
df_plot = df_plot.astype({'Class':'str'})
df_plot['percentage'] = df.groupby(['Type','label']).size().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100*x/float(x.sum())).values.round(2).astype(str)
df_plot['percentage'] = "(" + df_plot['percentage'] + '%)'

df_plot
###
       Type Class  count percentage
0         -     0      3    (75.0%)
1         -     1      1    (25.0%)
2     Array     1      2   (100.0%)
3  Sentence     0      1   (33.33%)
4  Sentence     1      2   (66.67%)
5    String     0      2   (100.0%)
```

```
fig = px.bar(df_plot,
             x='Type',
             y='count',
             color='Class',
             text=df_plot['count'].astype(str) + "<br>" + df_plot['percentage'],
             width=550,
             height=400,
             category_orders={'Type':['-','Array','Sentence','String']},
             template='plotly_white',
             log_y=True
             )
fig.show('browser')
```

[image]

---

with your CSV file followed the same ELT turning into `df_plot2`,
while **Class** `0` and `1` has a huge difference,
A stacked bar chart(default setting) won't give you **distinguishable** outcome,
we can use `barmode='group'` instead,

```
fig2 = px.bar(df_plot2,
              barmode='group',
              x='Type',
              y='count',
              color='Class',
              color_discrete_map={'0':'#5DA597', '1':'#FFC851'},
              text=df_plot2['count'].astype(str) + "<br>" + df_plot2['percentage'],
              width=850,
              height=800,
              category_orders={'Type': ['-', 'Array', 'Sentence', 'String']},
              template='plotly_white',
              log_y=True,
              )
fig2.update_yaxes(dtick=1)
fig2.show('browser')
```

[image]