# How to create and annotate a stacked proportional bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stacked-chart, plot-annotations

I'm struggling to create a stacked bar chart derived from `value_counts()` of a columns from a dataframe.

Assume a dataframe like the following, where `responder` is not important, but would like to stack the **count** of `[1,2,3,4,5]` for all `q#` columns.

```
responder, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5
------------------------------
r1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1
r2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2
r3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5
r4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2
r5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4
r6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1
r7, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5
```

Look something like, except each bar would be labled by `q#` and it would include 5 sections for count of `[1,2,3,4,5]` from the data:

[image]

Ideally, all bars will be "100%" wide, showing the count as a proportion of the bar.  But it's gauranteed that each `responder` row will have one entry for each, so the percentage is just a bonus if possible.

Any help would be much appreciated, with a slight preference for `matplotlib` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the heights of bars using percentages and obtain the stacked bar plot using `ax = percents.T.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)` where `percents` is a DataFrame with `q1,...q5` as columns and `1,...,5` as indices.

```
>>> percents
         q1        q2        q3        q4        q5
1  0.196873  0.199316  0.206644  0.194919  0.202247
2  0.205357  0.188988  0.205357  0.205357  0.194940
3  0.202265  0.217705  0.184766  0.196089  0.199177
4  0.199494  0.199494  0.190886  0.198481  0.211646
5  0.196137  0.195146  0.211491  0.205052  0.192174
```

Then you can use `ax.patches` to add labels for every bar. Labels can be generated from the original counts DataFrame: `counts = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())`

```
>>> counts
    q1   q2   q3   q4   q5
1  403  408  423  399  414
2  414  381  414  414  393
3  393  423  359  381  387
4  394  394  377  392  418
5  396  394  427  414  388
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## create some data similar to yours
np.random.seed(42)
categories = ['q1','q2','q3','q4','q5']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,6,size=(2000, 5)), columns=categories)

## counts will be used for the labels
counts = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())

## percents will be used to determine the height of each bar
percents = counts.div(counts.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

counts_array = counts.values
nrows, ncols = counts_array.shape
indices = [(i,j) for i in range(0,nrows) for j in range(0,ncols)]
percents_array = percents.values

ax = percents.T.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.01), loc='upper right')
for i, p in enumerate(ax.patches):
    ax.annotate(f"({p.get_width():.2f}%)", (p.get_x() + p.get_width() - 0.15, p.get_y() - 0.10), xytext=(5, 10), textcoords='offset points')
    ax.annotate(str(counts_array[indices[i]]), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() - 0.15, p.get_y() + 0.10), xytext=(5, 10), textcoords='offset points')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- From `matplotlib 3.4.2`, use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html).
- `pro = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)` creates a dataframe of proportions relative to each row. Note the importance of summing and dividing along the correct axis.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `kind='barh'` and `stacked=True` to plot the `pro` dataframe, which will create an x-axis with the correct range (0 - 1). `matplotlib` is the default plotting backend.
- `.bar_label` has a `labels` parameter, which accepts custom labels.

  - `labels` is created with a list comprehension, where the values (`vals`) from `df` are combined with the values from `per` for each bar patch.
  - `(w := v.get_width()) > 0` can be used to conditionally show annotations, greater than 0 in this case. `:=` is an assignment expression, available from `python 3.8`.

    - `labels = [f'{val}\n({w.get_width()*100:.1f}%)' for w, val in zip(c, vals)]` can be used if there's no need to check the patch size.
    - `labels = [f'{val}\n({w.get_width()*100:.1f}%)' if w.get_width() > 0 else '' for w, val in zip(c, vals)]` works without the `:=`, but requires using `.get_width()` twice.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.3.5`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe from OP
data = {'responder': ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6', 'r7'], 'q1': [5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4], 'q2': [3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3], 'q3': [2, 1, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2], 'q4': [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 1], 'q5': [1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 5]}

# The labels to be on the y-axis should be set as the index
# If the column names and index need to be swapped, use .T to transpose the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('responder')

# create dataframe with proportions
pro = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

# plot
ax = pro.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(12, 10), stacked=True)

# move legend
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.01), loc='upper left')

# column names from per used to get the column values from df
cols = pro.columns

# iterate through each group of containers and the corresponding column name
for c, col in zip(ax.containers, cols):
    
    # get the values for the column from df
    vals = df[col]

    # create a custom label for bar_label
    labels = [f'{val}\n({w*100:.1f}%)' if (w := v.get_width()) > 0 else '' for v, val in zip(c, vals)]
    
    # annotate each section with the custom labels
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center', fontweight='bold')
```

[image]

- Transposing `df` with `df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('responder').T`, swaps the index and columns, to produce the following plot. `figsize=(12, 10)` may need to be adjusted.

[image]

### DataFrames

- `df`

```py
           q1  q2  q3  q4  q5
responder                    
r1          5   3   2   4   1
r2          3   5   1   4   2
r3          2   1   3   4   5
r4          1   4   5   3   2
r5          1   2   5   3   4
r6          2   3   4   5   1
r7          4   3   2   1   5
```

- `per`

```py
                 q1        q2        q3        q4        q5
responder                                                  
r1         0.333333  0.200000  0.133333  0.266667  0.066667
r2         0.200000  0.333333  0.066667  0.266667  0.133333
r3         0.133333  0.066667  0.200000  0.266667  0.333333
r4         0.066667  0.266667  0.333333  0.200000  0.133333
r5         0.066667  0.133333  0.333333  0.200000  0.266667
r6         0.133333  0.200000  0.266667  0.333333  0.066667
r7         0.266667  0.200000  0.133333  0.066667  0.333333
```

### Referenced

- [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700614/7758804) shows various ways to format and move the legend.
- [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) provides a detailed explanation of `.bar_label`.
- [How to add multiple annotations to a barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61718351/7758804)
- [stack bar plot in matplotlib and add label to each section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64202669/7758804)
- [How to annotate barplot with percent by hue/legend group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851673/7758804)
- [How to add percentages on top of bars in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851142/7758804)