# Python code to make bar plot grouped by categorical variable (gender)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this:
[image: dataframe]
The dataframe is made by a groupby function and thereafter I have reset the index.
I'm trying to make a barplot with each score/grade grouped by gender. Thus 4 groups of bars.
With this code I don't get the desired output.
data_gender.plot(x='gender',kind='bar', stacked=False)

Comment: [SO How to create a grouped bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796264/how-to-create-a-grouped-bar-plot) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose your DF and use gender as index. try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'cat1': [4, 6], 'cat2': [8, 5], 'cat3': [3, 2]}
gender = ['female', 'male']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=gender).T

df.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Which yields:

[image]